# first-order logic sentence for graph

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm studying for my exam and I'd appreciate any help.

In this exercise we have the following first order signature : L = ($\varnothing$,P) and P = {$E^2, =^1,G^1 $}.

Here's an interpretation I of domain $D_I$ = {$v_0, v_1,v_2,v_3$ } with:

$E^I $= {$(v_0, v_0), (v_0, v_1), (v_0, v_2), (v_1,v_1), (v_2, v_0), (v_3 , v_0), (v_3 , v_1), (v_3 , v_2) $}

$ =^I $ = {$(v_0, v_0), (v_1,v_1), (v_2, v_2), (v_3 , v_3) $}

$ G^I $ = {$v_0, v_3$}

" I " can be considered as an oriented graph colored, where the relation of adjacency is denoted as "E", grey vertexes are denoted as " G ", and " = " represents equality.

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IprEP.png)

The question is: write a first order formula which represents the sentence "Every non grey vertex has exactly one edge leaving it".

I wrote this formula but I'm not sure if it's correct:

$((\forall x \lnot G(x)) \Rightarrow∃y E(x,y))∧∀x∀y∀z((E(x,y)∧E(x,z))⇒y=z) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantification over individuals that satisfy a given predicate usually does not follow the syntax that you use. Moreover, the statement about uniqueness is a condition satisfied by every non-grey vertex. So I would write

$$\forall x. \lnot G(x) \Rightarrow (\exists y E(x,y) \wedge \forall w \forall z. (E(x,w) \wedge E(x,z) \Rightarrow w = z))$$

The first conjunct in the conclusion of the implication expresses that there exists an edge leaving $x$. The second conjunct expresses that any two edges leaving $x$ have the same terminal endpoint.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation! is it correct if I add parentheses like this:
∀x.(.......)?     (after "for all x" and at the end of the formula)

Comment: Yes. Parentheses will do no harm.

Comment: I wanted to check if the interpretation $ " I " $ is a model of this formula, when I choose $x = v_3,  y = v_0, w = v_1, z = v_2 $ I find true but I thought it should be false because $ x = v_3 $ and we know that $ v_3 $ is a grey vertex. So I was wondering if finding true for this formula is a coherent result, thanks in advance.